# Namecheap port forwarding

Tags: networking, ssh, port-forwarding

I bought a domain name (say x.com) on namecheap. When I go to x.com using my web browser (port 80), I get my index.html since I'm running apache. But when I try `ssh user@x.com` I get `Connection refused`. When I ssh directly to the IP it works. Thus it is a problem with namecheap not forwarding port 22 (I also tried 53 and 443 to the same end. 80 worked, but I couldn't use it since my computer is also running apache). I tried chatting on customer support, the people had no idea what I was talking about. How can I get `ssh user@x.com` to work?

EDIT: Dig correctly resolved my IP. And again, it works when I use port 80, just I can't use that port because I need it for Apache. The issue is namecheap blocking all the other ports.

Comment: If you run `dig x.com`, do you get the correct IP of the server?

Comment: what specific services are you using from namecheap? and who hosts your dns, also namecheap or yourself?

Comment: Namecheap does not do port forwarding on a domain name.  Namecheap would simply resolve the name (`x.com`) to and IP address.  After that its up to your router/firewall to allow the ports to come through.  You'll need to make sure the name is resolving correctly using `nslookup` or `dig`.

Comment: @pete Namecheap hosts my DNS

Comment: I agree with @heavyd unless you have an specific reason as to why you are sure namecheap is involved with port-forwarding, your problem lies elsewhere. Are you inside or outside the network the ssh server is on while you are attempting to ssh in?

Comment: Outside! I'm telling you if I use the global ip directly it works!

Comment: I'm using my phone on data

Comment: have you only been using your phone to attempt this? are you setup for ipv6?

Comment: This is a bit confusing.  Are you saying you try to ssh to port 22 with the IP address and it works, but if you ssh to port 22 to the host name gets the connection refused?  This would seem to suggest a DNS problem, not something with port forwarding.